# swift3/4 to objective c ugly bridging due to camel casing in constructors

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there a notation that's less ugly than this:

```
@objc public init (NSError nserror: NSError) {
```

?

this is to have this:

```
[[MyErrorWrapperClass alloc] initWithNSError:error];
```

rather than an even ugluer that:

```
[[MyErrorWrapperClass alloc] initWithNserror:error];
```

on objc side for a cleaner swift signature:

```
@objc public init (nserror: NSError) {
```

Comment: Are you importing Swift code into Objective-C or vice versa? – And your two lines before and after *"rather than an even ugluer that"* are identical, which makes your question unclear.

Comment: What exactly is 'ugly'? Ugly is subjective... for example - "I think that your question's presentation is ugly". Having said that, this is what you need: `@objc(initWithNSError:)`

Comment: @MartinR the casing in those two is different.

Comment: @Alladinian Yes! Exactly what I was asking for: the remapper. Feel free to post as answer for acceptance and upvoting.

Comment: @AntonTropashko Done. Glad that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the real question here is 'How can I supply a custom signature for objc, on a swift function'

and the answer is to pass the singature in parentheses like this:

```
@objc(initWithNSError:)
public init (nserror: NSError) {
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: Allowed to clean the situation with nested swift classes exposed to objective c to avoid objc namespace pollution. Thanks a million!